# Android CursorLoader Listview

Tags: android, listview

I use a CursorLoader to query a database using a content provider to obtain values from the name column. I then populate it in a ListView using a SimpleCursorAdapter in the onCreate() method of my activity. I want to know if I should implement the adapter again in the onStart() method of the Activity, so that the list gets updated when I navigate to another activty and back to the listview. But I thought that wasn't necessary as a CursorLoader automatically listens to updations in the database. But my listview doesn't get populated when I return to the activity.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,com.example.test.R.layout.list_view , null,
            fromColumns, toViews,0);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    listview = getListView();
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    View addButton=findViewById(R.id.add);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Enter.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
    );
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LIST_ID, null, this);

}
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Uri CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://" + "com.example.test" + "/University");

    return new CursorLoader(this,CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);

}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
```

Comment: Did you also implement `onCreateLoader` and `onLoadFinished`?

Comment: Yes I did. I've included the code

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in `onLoadFinished`?

Comment: It was a completely different error. I failed to include the _ID argument in the PROJECTION string. Thank you for your suggestions.